# do I need to store domain names to md5 mode in database?

Tags: mysql, database

I had a feeling that searching domain names taking time more than as usual in mysql. actually domain name column has a unique index though query seems slow.

My question is do I need to convert to binary mode?? say md5 hash or something??

Comment: Why don't you start with an [explain query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)?  I don't think adding a 128-bit number to every row is going to help performance.  It's better to rely on MySQL's indices.

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with? And how slow is slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally keeping the domain names in a "VARCHAR" data type, with an UNIQUE index defined for that field, is the most simple & efficient way of managing your data.

Never try to use any complexity (like using Binary mode or "BLOB" data type), for the sake of one / two field(s), as it will further deteriorate your MySQL performance.

Hope it helps.